# Problems with the date attribute in HTML5

Tags: html

I have this code that I am building for my internship. I am trying to use the "date"input type in my code to add a pop up calender, however it isn't working. I have look at numerous websites, but i have yet to find someone who is having this problem. Any ideas on how to make this work? Here is my code:

```
<body>
  <h1> Time Logging Form</h1>
  <form method="post" id='datetime'>
    <div class="form-row" id='datacell'>
      <div class="editor-cell">
        <input type="date" id="date">
      </div>
      <div class="editor-cell">
        <input placeholder="Time in 00:00" type="text" id="timein">
      </div>
      <div class="editor-cell">
        <input placeholder="Time out 00:00" type="text" id="timeout">
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="+" id='plus'>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" id='submit'>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: If I run your code, the calendar pops up.

Comment: My Brouser did not support the atribute

Answer (score 1):

What exactly you want to do with data attributs? When you run this html code in your browser, the calendar appears:

https://jsfiddle.net/6w5b5r5h/

```
<body>
  <h1> Time Logging Form</h1>
  <form method="post" id='datetime'>
    ...
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help i figured out that this tribute is not supported in my browser yet, therefore it doesn't work.